# Node js html-pdf command not working from PHP

Tags: node.js, command, node-html-pdf

I am trying to create a PDF file from a HTML for which I am using npm html-pdf package. When I am trying to run this command from terminal

```
html-pdf ticket-2.html ticketpdf.pdf
```

its working fine and PDF is creating successfully.But when I am trying to run this command from a PHP file then its showing this error sh: html-pdf: command not found.

```
$ret = exec("html-pdf ticket-2.html ticketpdf.pdf", $out, $err);
print_r($out);
```

Output: Array ( [0] => sh: html-pdf: command not found )

Can anyone help me on this where this issue is exactly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you tell more about how are you trying to run this command from a PHP file? May be by adding your portion of code.

Comment: @shubhambharti201 I have edited my question and added the php script here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your php script is not able to access the path where `html-pdf` is installed. For Windows, It will be installed in `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm` assuming you would have installed it globally. Set this environment path in the scope of php script. It should work.

Edited: Try adding `$_ENV["PATH"]="/home/designed/bin";` before `$ret = exec("html-pdf ticket-2.html ticketpdf.pdf", $out, $err);`

Comment: In my server I have globally installed html-pdf here : /home/designed/bin. Can you please help me how to set up environment variable?